# Module '"../../@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Color' in chartjs-plugin-annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have to use chartjs-plugin-annotation in angular application. I have installed this plugin and I am getting below error

> Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'chart.js' resolves to an untyped module at '/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js', which cannot be augmented

I had googled and I get to use

```
npm install @types/chart.js
```

This resolved the previous error but it generating new errors like

> Module '"../../@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Color'.
>
> Module '"../../@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'FontSpec'.
>
> Module '"../../@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Plugin'.

What am I doing wrong here?

My Code is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, ChartOptions} from 'chart.js';

import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-financial-chart',
  templateUrl: './financial-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./financial-chart.component.css']
})
export class FinancialChartComponent implements OnInit {
  Linechart = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    Chart.plugins.register(annotationPlugin);
    
    
        const config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
              datasets: [{
                label: 'My First Dataset',
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                tension: 0.1
              }]
            },
            options: {
              plugins: {
                autocolors: false,
                annotation: {
                  annotations: {
                    box1: {
                      // Indicates the type of annotation
                      type: 'box',
                      xMin: 1,
                      xMax: 2,
                      yMin: 50,
                      yMax: 70,
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.25)'
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          };
    
    
this.Linechart.push( new Chart('canvas',config));

  }

}
```

my package.json is below
[image: package.json]

Comment: Are you doing `import { Color, FontSpec, Plugin } from '@types/chart.js';`? That would be incorrect. You should be importing them from the actual module, i.e. `import { Color, FontSpec, Plugin } from 'chart.js';`. The `@types` libraries are just for [type declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html). For further assistance please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you if we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @j1mbl3s Thanks for review, I have added my codes also for better understanding of problem.

Comment: Which version of `chart.js` and `chartjs-plugin-annotation` are you using? I see that `chart.js@3.3.2` bundles types with the package. If you are using a lower version that _does_ require `@types/chart.js`, you may be looking for the type [`Chart.ChartColor`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/index.d.ts#L681).

Comment: @j1mbl3s Thanks for help I am using chart.js@^2.9.4 and chartjs-plugin-annotation@^1.0.2. I have added a screenshot of my package.json also in question.

Comment: See the 3rd statement of the [README](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/blob/master/README.md) for `chartjs-plugin-annotation`: "For Chart.js 2.4.0 to 2.9.x support, use version 0.5.7 of this plugin" Your package.json lists dependencies on `chart.js@^2.9.4` and `chartjs-plugin-annotation@^1.0.2` which are incompatible.

Comment: @j1mbl3s Thanks for pointing the right issue. Now I can use this plugin easily. Thank you so much.